# To what extent was Apollo program training specific to each mission?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, training

In comments and answer to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27559/was-there-any-practical-advantage-to-having-different-crews-for-each-apollo-la), the time it takes to train for an Apollo mission is mentioned several times as a factor on the big rotation of crews. I figure that would actually play in favour of reusing crews, as most of that year of training would presumably be redundant.

I can only picture the amused looks if a white coat came to Armstrong and Aldring in sept 1969 and told them: Ok, today we're going to learn how to land on the Moon.

On the other hand, some of the training might be mission specific (scientific instruments, driving the buggy, ... )

So now I'm also curious to know to what extent a full crew would need to retrain if they where to be sent back to the Moon.

Comment: This is out there: https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/A11CrewTrainingSummaries.pdf  Pity there don't seem to be similar documents for the other missions, comparisons could be instructive.

Comment: While the majority of the training would not have been specific to a single landing mission, there was a lot of landing-site-specific training - recognizing the selenography, planning for geologic work, and so on. Somewhat fictionalized, but in the film *Apollo 13*, when Lovell is given the choice between replacing his command module pilot or having his crew bumped to a later mission, one of his objections is "we've trained for the Fra Mauro Highlands!" -- the site specific training was onerous enough that he didn't want to go through it again for a landing at Littrow.